# Datagrid doesn't refresh on changed data

Tags: c#, sql-server, silverlight, datagrid, wcf-ria-services

Is there any way to have a datagrid listen to the database and automatically update the data if the database data is changed? I use a SQL Server database.

I'd like to use Linq-2-SQL if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because @Slaggg asked: there are fairly straightforward ways of doing this, but they're almost certainly going to involve a lot of coding, it'll impact performance pretty significantly, and my strong suspicion is that it'll be more trouble than it's worth.

That said, for a typical n-tier application, at a very high level you'll need:

(1) A way to notify the middle tier when the data changes.  You could use custom-code triggers inside each the table that fire off some sort of notification (perhaps using WCF and CLR stored procedures), or you could use a [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7(VS.90).aspx) object.  Probably the second would work better.

(2) A way to notify each client connected to that middle tier.  Assuming that you're using WCF, you'll need to use one of the duplex bindings that are available, such as Net.TCP or HttpPollingDuplex (for Silverlight).  You'll need to make sure this is configured correctly on both the client and the server.  You'll also need to manually keep track of which clients might be interested in the update, so that you can know which ones to update, and you'll need to be able to remove them from that list when they go away or timeout.  Tomek, from the MS WCF team, has some pretty good examples on his [blog](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2009/11/pubsub-sample-with-wcf-nettcp-protocol.html) that you might want to investigate.

(3) A mechanism to update the local client's model and/or viewmodel and/or UI once you get the notification from the middle tier that something has changed.  This is more complicated than you'd think: it's difficult enough to keep your UI in sync with your data model under normal circumstances, but it gets dramatically more complicated when that data model can be changing under you from the other direction as well.

The *idea* behind these sorts of notifications is straightforward enough: but getting all the details right is likely to keep you debugging way into the night.  And the guy who has to support all this two years from now will curse your name.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends from where you are updating the database:

- From the same context (in
  Silverlight, are you adding,
  deleting, editing on the same page)
- From a ChildWindow in your
  Silverlight application
- From an
  external, non-related tool, outside
  of your Silverlight application

Comment: I'm so glad you ask that, and sorry for not providing that info in the first place. My silverlight app contains a tabcontrol, that contains UC's I consider implementing an ITabUserControl  interface that has a updateonselected method and then update the ui every time a tab is selected. There will be many clients, so I think SqlDependencies will cause a too heavy load. How does that sound to you guys?

Comment: I guess you'll have to consider "x users clicking y-tabs every z-time". If you have quite an amount of clients clicking away on your tabs I take it you will have a huge amount of traffic going back and forth depending on the amount of data required. Assuming you realize this, if you have a big enough of hardware to back up the traffic this will produce I don't see a problem with the SelectedTabChanged approach, although being web, I'd prefer a pagechange over a tabchange to present new data, where the users are more used to as seeing new data. Have you considered a refresh button?

Comment: This doesn't seem like it answers the question at all.  I'm stunned this is an accepted answer.  Still wondering - how do I get my datagrid to update when some external tool writes to the database?

Comment: @Slaggg first of all, thank you for the troll, secondly, he didn't get any replies for 2-3 months, so he might just have been happy that someone did actually care to try and help out and gave me a point. and lastly; I did raise further questions to continue helping but never got a responds back, so I didn't further elaborate on the subject; and as you are being so positively and constructive I do not intend to do so now neither.